# spring Criteria Builder array_agg(UUID)

Tags: spring, jpa, criteria-api

Hello i have simple query:

```
select record_key, array_agg(table.record_id) from table
group by record_key;

ID, RecordKey, RecordId
1,1,a9815de5-d132-46ef-bc43-8704031a1351
2,1,b9825de5-d132-46ef-bc43-8704031a1352
3,1,c9835de5-d132-46ef-bc43-8704031a1353
4,2,d9845de5-d132-46ef-bc43-8704031a1354
5,2,e9855de5-d132-46ef-bc43-8704031a1355
6,2,f9865de5-d132-46ef-bc43-8704031a1356
```

Result

```
2,"{d9845de5-d132-46ef-bc43-8704031a1354,e9855de5-d132-46ef-bc43-8704031a1355,f9865de5-d132-46ef-bc43-8704031a1356}"
1,"{a9815de5-d132-46ef-bc43-8704031a1351,b9825de5-d132-46ef-bc43-8704031a1352,c9835de5-d132-46ef-bc43-8704031a1353}"
```

I have to transform it to CriteriaBuilder query

```
 @Data
 public class GroupedResults {
    
        private int recordKey;
        private List<UUID> recordIds;
    
        public GroupedResults(int recordKey, UUID[] recordIds) {
            this.recordKey = recordKey;
            if (recordIds == null) {
                this.recordIds = Collections.emptyList();
            } else {
                this.recordIds = Arrays.stream(recordIds)
                        .map(UUID.class::cast)
                        .toList();
            }
        }
    }



@Override
public List<GroupedResults> getGroupedResult() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    var namedQuery = cb.createQuery(GroupedResults.class);
    var root = namedQuery.from(Table.class);

    namedQuery.select(cb.construct(GroupedResults.class,
            root.get(Table_.recordKey),
            cb.function(TablePostgresDialect.FUNCTION_ARRAY_AGG_UUID, UUID[].class, root.get(Table_.recordId))
    ));
    return entityManager.createQuery(namedQuery).getResultList();
}

@Slf4j
```

public class ArrayAggUuidSqlFunction extends StandardSQLFunction {

```
public ArrayAggUuidSqlFunction() {
    super("array_agg", new BasicTypeReference<>("uuid_arr", UUIDArrayType.class, 2003));
}

@Override
public void render(SqlAppender sqlAppender, List<? extends SqlAstNode> arguments, SqlAstTranslator<?> translator) {
    if (arguments.size() != 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("array_agg function must have exactly 1 argument");
    }
    sqlAppender.appendSql("(distinct %s)".formatted(arguments.get(0)));
}
```

}

Can somebody help me with this i am getting:
Could not determine appropriate instantiation strategy - no matching constructor found and one or more arguments did not define alias for bean-injection

Same function was working with JPQL but i have to go with criteria builder now, i am not sure if i have wrong query or pojo mapping.
Thank you.